# Why is sizeof(msg) shorter than the string?

Tags: c, pointers

I have just started to learn how to program and I am using this book called Head First C. There are sections in the book called *Brain Power*. In one of these sections it was written.

```
void fortune_cookie(char msg[])
{
  printf("Message reads: %s\n", msg);
  printf("msg occupies %i bytes\n", sizeof(msg));
}
```

The output:

> Cookies make you fat
>
> msg occupies 8 bytes

The Brain Power question was: Why do you think `sizeof(msg)` is shorter than the length of the whole string? What is `msg`? Why would it return different sizes on different machines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the 'sizeof'(a pointer pointing to an array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case

```
 char msg[]
```

is same as

```
 char * msg
```

so what you're really seeing is the output of `sizeof(char *)`.

As the size of a pointer is dependent on the architecture/compiler, you'll see different output in different machine.

Also, please note, as the `sizeof` operator produces a result of type `size_t`, you should be using `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Answer (score 3):

**Why do you think sizeof(msg) is shorter than the length of the whole string?**

Because `arrays` decay to pointers when passed as parameters to some function.

```
int arr[10];
printf("%zu", sizeof(arr));
```

This would return `40`. Considering size of `int` is `4`

But when sent to a function

```
void func(int arr[])
{
    printf("%lu", sizeof(arr));
}
```

This would return `sizeof(int*)`

---

**What is msg?**

`msg` is an array of `char` that is sent to the function.

---

**Why would it return differentsizes on different machines?**

Because the size of the memory address would be different for different machines architectures, thus making `sizeof(int*)` different.

Answer (score 2):

The following piece of code should Answer to your Question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(char *msg){
    printf("\n");
    printf("Sizeof MSG = %zu\n", sizeof(msg));
    printf("Length of MSG = %zu\n", strlen(msg));
}

int main(void) {

    char msg[10] = "Michi";
    printf("Sizeof MSG = %zu\n", sizeof(msg));
    printf("Length of MSG = %zu\n", strlen(msg));

    foo(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Sizeof MSG = 10
Length of MSG = 5

Sizeof MSG = 8
Length of MSG = 5
```

Why is `Sizeof MSG = 10` inside `main` ? Because you print the size of the Array.

Why is `Sizeof MSG = 8` inside `foo` ? Because you print the size of the Pointer, which on your machine (like mine) happens to be `8`.

Arrays decays to pointer to its first element, when are used as Function arguments.

In other words, things like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(int *msg){
    printf("\n");
    printf("Sizeof MSG = %zu\n", sizeof(msg));
    printf("Length of MSG = %zu\n", strlen(msg));
}

int main(void) {

    int msg[10] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("Sizeof MSG = %zu\n", sizeof(msg));
    printf("Length of MSG = %zu\n", strlen(msg));

    foo(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Will not work and probably your compiler will warn you about that:

```
error: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type
```

Because `strlen` is defined like this:

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
```

As you can see `strlen` need a `char*` and not an `int*`.

To fix it you need to pass the length too, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(int *msg, size_t length){
    size_t i=0;

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Sizeof MSG = %zu\n",length);
    for (i = 0; i<length;i++){
        printf("%d ",msg[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int msg[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    size_t length = sizeof msg / sizeof msg[0];
    size_t i=0;

    printf("\n");
    printf("Sizeof MSG = %zu\n",length);
    for (i = 0; i<length;i++){
        printf("%d ",msg[i]);
    }


    foo(msg, length);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Sizeof MSG = 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

Sizeof MSG = 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: You mean `piece` not `peace`

Answer (score 0):

In C strings and arrays are not first-class data types so cannot be *passed-by-copy*.  Although the argument type syntax `char msh[]` is supported, it has identical semantics to `char* msg`. The array argument syntax does little more than to serve to indicate to the human developer that the function expects `msg` to refer to an array rather then a pointer to a single item.

Where `msg` is a nul terminated string, or an array with a sentinel value, there may be no need to pass the array length, but in many cases it is useful to do so.

A trick you can use is to wrap the array in a `struct` which is a first class type and can be passed by copy or pointer.  Passing by pointer is usually preferable for performance reasons, but either way the size of the member is known.

```
typedef struct { char data[32] ; } sMsgContainer ;

void fortune_cookie( const sMsgContainer msg )
{
  printf( "Message reads: %s\n", msg.data ) ;
  printf( "msg occupies %i bytes\n", sizeof(msg) ) ;
  printf( "msg.data occupies %i bytes\n", sizeof(msg.data) ) ;
}


void fortune_cookie2( sMsgContainer* msgp )
{
  printf( "Message reads: %s\n", msgp.data ) ;
  printf( "msgp occupies %i bytes\n", sizeof(msgp) ) ;
  printf( "msgp->data occupies %i bytes\n", sizeof(msg->data) ) ;
}
```

Then given:

```
sMsgContainer msg = {"Cookies make you happy"} ;
fortune_cookie( msg ) ;
fortune_cookie2( &msg ) ;
```

The output

```
Message reads: Cookies make you happy
msg occupies 32 bytes
msg.data occupies 32 bytes
Message reads: Cookies make you happy
msgp occupies 4 bytes
msgp->data occupies 32 bytes
```

It is possible for the length of `msg` to be greater than `msg.data` for alignment purposes, but that is implementation defined.